BLUEZ - jammy Release' does not have a Release file
I wanted to sudo apt update, and then i got the following message. Recently the bluetooth wasn't working very well on my machine.
E: The repository    'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu jammy    Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a    repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by    default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and    user configuration details.

The other issues I was encountering was the following: and had issues with chip-tool (Matter) connected to bluetooth:
Pairing Failure: src/platform/Linux/bluez/BluezObjectManager.cpp:312: CHIP Error 0x000000AC: Internal error
I presume my bluez packages might be harmed. Still got no idea how to fix them.
Does anyone know how to resolve the bluetooth problem?
Thank you!

The repository    'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu' does not have a setup-variant matching your version of Ubuntu. Remove any install you have done based on it and the .../sources.list.d/ content. Then try find a replacement.

Thank you! Which command(s) should I use for it?

PPAs are 3rd party sources (ie. Personal Package Archives) where the only security checks are those you perform yourself, a quick check of https://launchpad.net/~bluetooth/+archive/ubuntu/bluez would show it's not maintained & shouldn't have been added except for EOL releases of years ago..  Did you check?

If it was me, I'd just edit your software sources & remove the unwanted line; but it can be done in other ways too (depending on course if using Desktop or Server which you never specified)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Just to clarify: I'm using Desktop :D

I checked my bluetooth service: there were 2 errors.
bluetoothd[11271]: Failed to clear UUIDs: Failed (0x03) bluetoothd[11271]: Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
